# Wget returned a webpage instead of a file?

Tags: cmd

When I try

`wget --no-check-certificate --output-document=example.txt https://url_to_file`

It downloads a **.html file** not a **txt file** and i don't want the webpage i want the file itself
so anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available. PowerShell used to have an alias `wget` for `Invoke-WebRequest`, but it is not an alias in pwsh 7.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$c=Get-Credential;(Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/TestJsonCommand.cs).Content | Out-File -FilePath 'C:/src/TestJsonCommand.cs' -Encoding ascii"
```

If the site has no password protection, then you will not need a `-Credential` parameter.